# How to get the correct implementation by condition

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have three classes of messages.

```
public class ByteMessage extends Message {
    private byte[] message;
    private long size;    
    public ByteMessage() {
        this.setReceiverType(ReceiverType.FILE);
    }

   //getters and setters
}

public class CharMessage extends Message {
    private char[] message;
    public CharMessage() {
        this.setReceiverType(ReceiverType.FILE);
    }
}
public class TextMessage extends Message {
    private String message;
    public TextMessage() {
        this.setReceiverType(ReceiverType.DB);
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

They are inherited from the message class `Message`.

```
public class Message {
    private ReceiverType receiverType;
    public ReceiverType getReceiverType() {
        return receiverType;
    }
    public void setReceiverType(ReceiverType receiverType) {
        this.receiverType = receiverType;
    }
}
```

The class has a field `receiverType` that defines where the message will be written. And now I have two receivers where a message can be recorded: DbReceiver and FileReceiver:

```
public class DbReceiver implements Receiver {
    @Override
    public void writeMessage(Message message) {
        //do something
    }
}

public class FileReceiver implements Receiver {
    @Override
    public void writeMessage(Message message) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

And I have a service that processes messages and which should, depending on the type of message, cause one or another implementation. How can I do this - get the right implementation?

```
public class Service {

    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        Receiver receiver = ???
        receiver.writeMessage(message);
    }
}
```

I know the solution with 'Map', but it doesn't look too good for me. Perhaps there are other solutions?

```
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    private Map<ReceiverType, Receiver> receiverMap;

    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        Receiver receiver = getReceiver(message.getReceiverType());
        receiver.writeMessage(message);
    }

    private Receiver getReceiver(ReceiverType receiverType){
        return receiverMap.get(receiverType);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to provide the instance of the receiver in the `ReceiverType` enum:

*Update:* Implementations of the receiver may be injected into enum values using special `@Component` with autowired receivers and `@PostConstruct` method:

```java
public enum ReceiverType {
    DB,
    FILE;

    private Receiver receiver = null;

    private void setReceiver(Receiver receiver) {
        if (null == this.receiver && null != receiver) {
            this.receiver = receiver;
        }
    }

    public Receiver getReceiver() {
        return this.receiver;
    }

    @Component
    public static class ReceiverInjector {
        @Autowired
        private DbReceiver db;

        @Autowired
        private FileReceiver file;

        @PostConstruct
        public void postConstruct() {
            ReceiverType.DB.setReceiver(db);
            ReceiverType.FILE.setReceiver(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Receiver implementations should be marked with `@Component` annotation too:

```java
@Component
public class DbReceiver implements Receiver {
    @Override
    public void writeMessage(Message message) {
        //do something
    }
}

@Component
public class FileReceiver implements Receiver {
    @Override
    public void writeMessage(Message message) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Then the service may be implemented as simply as follows:

```java
public class Service {

    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        message.getReceiverType().getReceiver().writeMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is an interesting solution. But unfortunately, I use Spring, and creating objects via new will give me objects that Spring doesn't manage. It is problem for me

Comment: @Violetta, I provided the update which should inject the receiver implementations into the enum.